# Запятая перед "как бог"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в данном случае.

> Он даже не рассматривает возможности того, что другие тоже как-то
>   влияют на его жизнь. **То есть ведёт себя(,) как бог**.

Мне кажется, что все-таки нужна, это сравнительный оборот "подобно богу". С другой стороны, этот оборот тесно связан со сказуемым и  без него предложение теряет смысл. Смущает, что в подобных фразах запятые не ставят: "ведешь себя как девчонка", "повел себя как идиот", "звери ведут себя как люди"...

Answer (score 5):

**В этом случае возможны варианты.**

С первого взгляда кажется, что обособлять оборот не нужно: ***То есть ведёт себя  как бОг.***

Но обращает на себя внимание присоединительный союз ТО ЕСТЬ. Это значит, что в контексте уже есть информация о поведении, и тогда постановка ударения на глаголе  кажется обоснованной: ***То есть ведЁт себя,  как бОг.***

**Пояснение**

1)Во многих случаях в сочетании "ведет себя как..." запятая не ставится, так как **семантика глагола не выражена без сравнительного оборота**. Это и называется тесной связью со сказуемым. **В этом случае ударение падает только на оборот, но не на глагол.**

Примеры:

Михайлов и **ведёт себя как старожил** ― просит кофе, прохаживается, привычно и со знанием роется на книжной полке. [Владимир Маканин. (1977)]

Она и сама **ведет себя как ребенок.** [Е. Кучеренко.  (2015.09.21)]

Живет в крепости, под охраной американских войск, называется президентом. А **ведет себя как король.** [Евгений Пахомов.// «Огонек», 2014]

2) **Во многих, но не всегда.** Надо смотреть структуру и семантику предложения. Иногда не выделяются запятой распространенные обороты, но и это не главное.

Как мне кажется, оборот может не выделяться запятой, если в контексте **уже есть конкретная информация о поведении, и тогда сравнительный оборот обобщает его тип.** **При обособлении ударение падает и на глагол, и на оборот.**

Например:

На прямые обвинения всякого рода посредственностей от искусства в том, что художник **ведЁт себя, как матерый делЯга,** копируя десятки раз свои работы и продавая копии в разные места, он отвечал любимой строчкой любимого поэта: «Не продается вдохновенье, но можно рукопись продать». [Валерий Роньшин. 2013]